# Searching multiple values in sql table, with a range

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table that contains some ingredients. Example:

```
 id | title | ingredients 
 1  | ex1   | ketchup, chicken, salt, honey, mountain dew
 2  | ex2   | beef, pepper, chili, honey, salt
```

And when the user searchs for the ingredients like:

```
ketchup, salt, honey
```

I generate a sql-query:

```
select * from recipes where( 
(ingredients LIKE '%ketchup%')
AND (ingredients LIKE '%salt%')
AND (ingredients LIKE '%honey%')
```

And it returns all recipes containing these specific ingredients, and it works grey.

Now. I've added a range-slider, to pick how many of the entered ingredients that should match for the search to return anything. Lets say i chose that 2 ingredients should match at least, i want to make a PHP function that outputs a sql string that pairs everyone of the entered ingredients, but i simply don't have the mindset for it.
Example:

```
  (ingredients LIKE '%ketchup%') AND (ingredients LIKE '%salt%')
  OR 
  (ingredients LIKE '%ketchup%') AND (ingredients LIKE '%honey%')
  OR
  So on. So ketchup & salt pair, ketchup & honey pair, salt & honey pair.
```

And of course variable so theres no limit to the ingredients inputted. I've tried for hours but no success. Hope i've explained my self clearly & someone will be able to help or teach me something :-)

My php function that does the current string looks like this:

```
$c_soeg = "ketchup, whatever, whatever. etc";
$c_ing_arr = explode(",", $c_soeg);
$c_count_arr = count($c_ing_arr);
$i = 0;
$c_sql = "SELECT * FROM recipes WHERE (";
while($i < $c_count_arr){
    $c_sql .= "(ingredients LIKE '%".trim($c_ing_arr[$i])."%')";
    if($i != $c_count_arr-1){
        $c_sql .= " AND ";
    }
    $i++;
}
$c_sql .= ")";
```

And the variable that contains the value of the range is named

```
$c_range;
```

Comment: Stopped reading in 3rd line, when the comma separated values appeared. Don't do that. Read about normalization.

Comment: DB Normalization, do you speak it?

Comment: This was just a example, i know about normalization but does not solve the problem

Comment: @user2979822: Oh, it would. With a table of ingredients you would use the having clause and be done with the task. Moreover you wouldn't mix apple and pineapple with %apple%.

Comment: Okay I can see that, but problem is that in the ingredients column i have amounts of the ingredient too. How exactly would i do that? Forgive me, i'm not that experienced in sql.

Comment: @user2979822 You should have three tables (e.g. recipes, ingredients, recipes_ingredients). In the table that relates recipes to ingredients (recipe_ingredient) you could have a column for quantity and a column for unit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of AND and OR conditions count the met criteria. This example gives you all records where at least two ingredients match:

```
select * from recipes
where
  case when ingredients like '%ketchup%' then 1 else 0 end
  +
  case when ingredients like '%salt%' then 1 else 0 end
  +
  case when ingredients like '%honey%' then 1 else 0 end
  > = 2;
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you should make 3 tables meaning
one for the title and another for the ingredients and one to connect them

```
    recipy
    id  | title |
     1  | ex1   | 
     3  | ex2   |

    recipyingredients
    recipyid | ingredientsid
           1 | 1
           1 | 2
           1 | 3
           1 | 4
           1 | 5
           2 | 1
           2 | 6
           2 | 7           

    ingredients
     id | ingredients 
     1  | ketchup
     2  | chicken
     3  | salt
     4  | honey
     5  | mountain dew
     6  | beef
     7  | pepper
```

In that case one recipy can have many ingredients and viceversa
The database would be clearer and you would not have to use like % as much.
Also you do not have to write the same ingredients every time for a recipy

Comment: You can also add the amount of the ingredient in the recipyingredients table

Comment: Thanks for reply. Problem is that its the user that writes the ingredients, like "200 bananas, 5 bottles of ketchup", and so on. Just think it would be really complicated to split all that up, into different tables. People have different ways of putting things too.

Comment: @user2979822 It will be probably a bit complicated, but definitely the right way to do things. Remember, that the right way always needs more work, but it pays off at the end. You need to validate the user input and decide what to allow/disallow them to type in. The problem you're facing now is the direct result of no taking control. You need to take ownership and control over your app and architecture.

Comment: A nice user interface can deal with those problems. This is a much more useful design.

Comment: That is always a problem to interpret what people write, but I am guessing that you make people input from a webpage? You could give them limited actions aka a controlled vocabulary. What I mean an amount text input, a drop-down menu what measure they can have (bottles, liters ...) and then a drop-down menu with the ingredients (which also can make them add new ingredients)